# Merge 2 Excel files with different columns, using a user form to select files and then column mapping

Tags: excel, vba

I need to merge two Excel files, but only certain columns from each. I need to use a userform to select the two files to merge and then also use column mapping to select which columns from each sheet need appear where in the new output sheet.

So far I have this.

```
Private Sub AddFilesButton_Click()
    Dim arrFiles As Variant

    On Error GoTo ErrMsg

    'Let the user choose the files they want to merge
    #If Mac Then
        arrFiles = Select_File_Or_Files_Mac()
    #Else
        arrFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls; *.xlsx), *.xls;*.xlsx", 1, "Choose Excel Files", "Select", True)
    #End If

    If IsNull(arrFiles) Or UBound(arrFiles) = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Please choose at least one Excel file"
    Else
        For Each file In arrFiles
            FilesListBox.AddItem file
        Next file
        MergeButton.Enabled = True
    End If

ErrMsg:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "There was an error. Please try again. [" & Err.Description & "]"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub MergeButton_Click()
    Dim fileName As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim s As Sheet1
    Dim thisSheet As Sheet1
    Dim lastUsedRow As Range
    Dim columnMap As Collection
    Dim filePath As Variant
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim insertAtRowNum As Integer
    Dim outColName As String
    Dim colName As String
    Dim fromRange As String
    Dim fromRangeToCopy As Range
    Dim toRange As String

    On Error GoTo ErrMsg

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set thisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    For i = 0 To FilesListBox.ListCount - 1
        fileName = FilesListBox.List(i, 0)
        'Get the map of columns for this file
        Set columnMap = MapColumns(fileName)

        'Open the spreadsheet in ReadOnly mode
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fileName, ReadOnly:=True)
        For Each sourceSheet In wb.Sheets

            'Get the used range (i.e. cells with data) from the opened spreadsheet
            If firstRowHeaders And i > 0 Then 'Only include headers from the first spreadsheet
                Dim mr As Integer
                mr = wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                Set dataRange = wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(mr - 1)
            Else
                Set dataRange = wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            End If

            For Each col In dataRange.Columns
                'Get corresponding output column. Empty string means no mapping
                colName = GetColName(col.Column)
                outColName = GetOutputColumn(columnMap, colName)
                If outColName <> "" Then
                    fromRange = colName & 1 & ":" & colName & dataRange.Rows.Count
                    Set fromRangeToCopy = dataRange.Range(fromRange)
                    fromRangeToCopy.Copy

                    toRange = outColName & insertAtRowNum & ":" & outColName & (insertAtRowNum + fromRangeToCopy.Rows.Count - 1)
                    thisSheet.Range(toRange).PasteSpecial
                End If
                Next col

            insertAtRowNum = insertAtRowNum + dataRange.Rows.Count
        Next sourceSheet

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Set wb = Nothing

    #If Mac Then
    'Do nothing. Closing workbooks fails on Mac for some reason
    #Else
    'Close the workbooks except this one
    Dim file As String
    For i = 0 To FilesListBox.ListCount - 1
        file = FilesListBox.List(i, 0)
        file = Right(file, Len(file) - InStrRev(file, Application.PathSeparator, , 1))
        Workbooks(file).Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next i
#End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload Me
ErrMsg:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "There was an error. Please try again. [" & Err.Description & "]"
    End If
End Sub

Function MapColumns(fileName As Variant) As Object
    Dim colMap As New Collection
    Select Case fileName
    Case "ExcelFile1.xlsx"
        colMap.Add Key:="C", Item:="A"
        colMap.Add Key:="D", Item:="B"
        colMap.Add Key:="E", Item:="C"
        colMap.Add Key:="I", Item:="D"
    Case "ExcelFile2.xlsx"
        colMap.Add Key:="B", Item:="F"
        colMap.Add Key:="J", Item:="G"
        colMap.Add Key:="H", Item:="H"
        colMap.Add Key:="C", Item:="I"
    End Select
    Set MapColumns = colMap
End Function

Function GetOutputColumn(columnMap As Collection, col As String) As String
    Dim outCol As String
    outCol = ""
    If columnMap.Count > 0 Then
        outCol = columnMap.Item(col)
    End If
    GetOutputColumn = outCol
End Function

'From: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/16444-getting-column-name-given-column-number.html
Function GetColName(ColumnNumber)
    FuncRange = Cells(1, ColumnNumber).AddressLocal(False, False) 'Creates Range (defaults Row to 1) and retuns Range in xlA1 format
    FuncColLength = Len(FuncRange) 'finds length of range reference
    GetColName = Left(FuncRange, FuncColLength - 1) 'row always "1" therefore take 1 away from string length and you are left with column ref
End Function

'From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh710200%28v=office.14%29.aspx#odc_xl4_ta_ProgrammaticallySelectFileforMac_DifferencesWindowsandMac
Function Select_File_Or_Files_Mac() As Variant
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyScript As String
    Dim MyFiles As String
    Dim MySplit As Variant
    Dim N As Long
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim mybook As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    MyPath = MacScript("return (path to documents folder) as String")
    'Or use MyPath = "Macintosh HD:Users:Ron:Desktop:TestFolder:"

    ' In the following statement, change true to false in the line "multiple
    ' selections allowed true" if you do not want to be able to select more
    ' than one file. Additionally, if you want to filter for multiple files, change
    ' {""com.microsoft.Excel.xls""} to
    ' {""com.microsoft.excel.xls"",""public.comma-separated-values-text""}
    ' if you want to filter on xls and csv files, for example.
    MyScript = _
    "set applescript's text item delimiters to "","" " & vbNewLine & _
               "set theFiles to (choose file of type " & _
             " {""com.microsoft.Excel.xls"",""org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet""} " & _
               "with prompt ""Please select a file or files"" default location alias """ & _
               MyPath & """ multiple selections allowed true) as string" & vbNewLine & _
               "set applescript's text item delimiters to """" " & vbNewLine & _
               "return theFiles"

    MyFiles = MacScript(MyScript)
    On Error GoTo 0

    MySplit = False 'Assume no files = cancel

    If MyFiles <> "" Then
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With

        MySplit = Split(MyFiles, ",")

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
    Select_File_Or_Files_Mac = MySplit
End Function

Function bIsBookOpen(ByRef szBookName As String) As Boolean
' Contributed by Rob Bovey
    On Error Resume Next
    bIsBookOpen = Not (Application.Workbooks(szBookName) Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to look through - where isn't your code working? All of it, or just parts?

Comment: Hi BruceWayne. The code seems to be working in that I no longer get any error messages and it appears to run, however there is no data coming through to the output sheet. The process simply ends with the two original sheets being open and no new, merged output sheet. I suspect the issue is with the looping process of copying and pasting selected columns.

Comment: What I have created so far is a based on code combined from two different methods, which can be found here: https://www.joinedupdata.com/the-ultimate-guide-on-how-to-merge-excel-files/how-to-merge-excel-files-with-the-same-columns#form-merge https://www.joinedupdata.com/the-ultimate-guide-on-how-to-merge-excel-files/how-to-merge-excel-files-with-the-same-columns